# Busca dinâmica como php e SQL Server não traz resultado?

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou com problemas em uma parte do código...

Tenho 5 campos a serem pesquisados com input, e eles fazem uma chamada no banco de dados e completam com os respectivos dados...

Porém dentre esses 5 campos , 2 não estão trazendo nenhum resultado!! Por favor ajude-me !!!

Código do select com o echo da tabela:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    numero AS NUMERO,
    parcli.descricao AS DESCRIÇÃO,
    (SELECT top 1 db.cli.descricao
        FROM db.cli, db.out 
        WHERE outseq = prosequen
            AND outcliseq = clisequen
        ORDER BY outposica desc
    ) as OUTRA_PARTE,
    ISNULL(
        (SELECT db.cli.descricao + ' / ' AS [text()] FROM db.cli, db.PROPRA WHERE PRAPROSEQ = PROSEQUEN AND PRAADVSEQ = db.cli.CLISEQUEN AND db.cli.CLIADVTIP = 1 ORDER BY db.cli.descricao FOR XML PATH('')),' -'
    ) AS ADVOGADOS,
    ISNULL(ctrdescri ,'-') as CONTRATO
    FROM db.propro
        LEFT JOIN db.proprc on prcproseq = prosequen
        LEFT JOIN db.cli parcli on prcclnseq = parcli.clisequen 
        LEFT JOIN db.timctr on prcctrseq = ctrsequen
    WHERE protiposs = 1
        AND proencerr = 2
        AND numero like '%".utf8_decode($_POST['numero']). "%'
        AND descricao like '%".utf8_decode($_POST['parte'])."%'
        AND descricao like '%".utf8_decode($_POST['outra'])."%'
        AND descricao like '%".utf8_decode($_POST['nome'])."%'
        AND ctrdescri like '%".utf8_decode($_POST['contrato'])."%' 
    ";

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conexion, $sql );
```

-

```
while($escrever=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){           

    echo'<tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; color: #333; background-color: #f0f0f0; ; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #aaa;">'.utf8_encode($escrever[0]).'</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; background-color: #f0f0f0; ; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #aaa; width: 14%;">'.utf8_encode($escrever[1]).'</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; color: #333; background-color: #f0f0f0; ; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #aaa;">'.utf8_encode($escrever[2]).'</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; color: #333; background-color: #f0f0f0; ; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #aaa;">'.utf8_encode($escrever[3]).'</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; color: #333; background-color: #f0f0f0; ; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #aaa;">'.utf8_encode($escrever[4]).'</td>

        </tr>';

    }
}
```

"
Nos campos "Nome" e "outra" se eu pesquisar em um dos dois, ele procura na coluna "parte" , então ele esta "perdido"...

obs: nos nomes das tabelas sao fictícios!

Comment: Poderia informar em qual tabela está cada uma das colunas da cláusula WHERE? // Se alterar o código acrescentando _alias_ para cada tabela, e usando esse _alias_ para identificar as colunas, facilita a compreensão do código por terceiros.

Comment: Você deveria construir a cláusula WHERE de forma dinâmica. Somente colocar restrição para os campos input que tenham sido informados.

Comment: "numero" esta na tabela "numero" e "descricao" esta na tabela "parcli"

Comment: Consegui , apenas troquei a variável onde faz o like , pelo select de cada coluna. Sendo assim, ficou dinâmica ! Podem fechar...